# How to detect windows soft keyboard in electron/chromium app?

Tags: windows, keyboard, electron

I'm building an electron app designed to run full screen on an MS Surface tablet. The app needs to function with the attachable hardware keyboard, and with the onscreen "soft" keyboard.

The problem is that the soft keyboard is often displayed over the fields being edited! How do I prevent this?

It doesn't look like the viewport is resized like it is on mobile.

Does the keyboard showing emit any kind of event I can catch and change the size of or move my form to accommodate it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Electron doesn't provide APIs to control or detect soft (virtual) keyabords. When it comes to opening/closing soft keyboards, Chromium is responsible for handling everything. So, it's actually a Chromium issue. Unfortunately, Chromium doesn't emit an event for opening/closing soft keyboards.

You may want to track the issue at:

https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/6430

Comment: Thanks. I've adjust the question not to pick on electron. But regardless of where the solution should stem from, is there a way to interact with a windows soft keyboard from a chrome/electron app?

Comment: I'm sure you've Googled this issue also, but there doesn't seem to be a way to interact with the soft keyboard. If the app is running in fullscreen mode, checking for height change may be an option. Of course, if the virtual keyboard is simply displayed over the input area (instead of popping up from the bottom as in iPads), checking for height change wouldn't work..

Comment: Yeah - it would be nice the keyboard made the window shorter like it does on the mobile web, but that doesn't seem to be the case...